# How do I remove an AF confirm chip?

Tags: nikon, dandelion-chip

I have a thin adapter from M42 to Nikon F made by Pixco (as sold on Ebay, [random example](https://www.ebay.com/itm/231575973416)). The  Nikon-compatible AF confirm chip glued to the adapter does not work anymore due to a broken pin. As a replacement, I already have a Pixco chip that came loose from another adapter, or a (slightly smaller) Dandelion chip.

What is the best method to remove and replace the chip, besides buying a new adapter?

Is there a different procedure to remove the chip from a lens?

Comment: I love how they call it a 'macro' adapter… meaning it won't focus to infinity. You know you can get M42s correctly modded to infinity for about $£€ 50? Just switch the camera to fully manual & the AF confirmation light works just fine, you just have no light metering because it can't read the aperture.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Yes, I have a modified Helios 44-3, so infinity is no problem here. I'm used to focus manually from the old days before AF, the chips are mostly for metering.

Comment: Depends on how it's fastened.  I'm assuming it's glued in.  I'd start with a heat gun and see if that works.

Comment: @dgatwood It looks like normal glue, not superglue. I'll try the temperature route on the weekend.